# Move hidden icons into two rows

Tags: interface, settings

In Blender, especially in the UV editing layout, I have the problem that I can't see some icons. There is not enough space for all icons in one row! How can I move them in two or more rows?

[image: hidden_icons]

Comment: It is not possible, you can use the mouse wheel

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! From the [Blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/interface/window_system/regions.html#scrolling): *"A region can be scrolled vertically and/or horizontally by dragging it with the MMB."*